# Which Lego set has had the most Easter Eggs?

Tags: sets

With the release of the new Harry Potter Hogwarts Castle (set: 71043)

[image]

has 6,020 pieces. I believe this a subtle reference (Easter egg) to the Lego set 6020, one of the first sets to ever have a wizard.

[image]

**Q:** With subtle references like this as one example, which set has had the most Easter Eggs so far, and what were they?

Comment: I am not aware of a list with the most easter eggs, but here is a [Top 25 by Just2good](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mC-ohovEfpM), and an article on [theBrickBlogger](http://thebrickblogger.com/2017/06/discovering-easter-eggs-in-lego-sets/).

Answer (score 7):

I'll say set [40523-1 Easter Rabbits](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=40523-1), which clearly (and unarguably) has **five** easter eggs:

[image: set 40523]